# Is it possible to get the no of button clicks using the google Analytics Reporting API v4?

Tags: hadoop, google-analytics, hdfs, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I have a requirement to ingest the data from google analytics into HDFS. So when analyzing I found google analytics reporting API, with which i can get the pageviews with respect to the particular date by changing the metrics and dimension from the below sample in the link.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java

But i have other requirements like

1. To get the no of button clicks in a certain page
2. And To find the traffic of a specific page from a specific site
   (ex: I want to find the traffic of https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab visited from https://stackoverflow.com)

Is this possible? I couldn't find any specific lead after this? Can anyone guide me with some examples or ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Are you tracking button clicks in your google analytics? Only page URLs will be tracked automatically by google analytics (if analytics code is available on the page). Events like a form submit/button click/downloads should be tracked manually using analytics [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

Comment: @SathishkumarJayaraj Yes, we are tracking the button clicks(I came to know about this by contacting our google analytics team). Now I even figured out a way to find the no of button clicks by using the metrics as "ga:totalEvents" and dimension as "ga:eventLabel". Thanks for telling me about events. Now i have to figure out a way to solve my second requirement.